# Rails; Fetch records within initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been wondering it is common to fetch records within initializer?

Here this is an example for service object to fetch records and generated pdf receipt file.

Input is invoice `uuid`, and fetch the related records such as card detail, invoice items within initialier.

```
    class Pdf::GenerateReceipt
      include Service

      attr_reader :invoice, :items, :card_detail

      def initialize(invoice_uuid)
        @invoice ||= find_invoice!(invoice_uuid) # caching
        @items = invoice.invoice_items
        @card_detail = card_detail
      end
      .....

      def call
        return ReceiptGenerator.new(
          id: invoice.uuid, # required
          outline: outline, # required
          line_items: line_items, # required
          customer_info: customer_info
        ) 
      rescue => e
        false, e
      end

     .....

      def card_detail
        card_metadata = Account.find(user_detail[:id]).credit_cards.primary.last

        card_detail = {}
        card_detail[:number] = card_metadata.blurred_number
        card_detail[:brand] = card_metadata.brand
        card_detail
      end
   end

Pdf::GenerateReceipt.('28ed7bb1-4a3f-4180-89a3-51cb3e621491') # => then generate pdf
```

The problem is if the records not found, this generate an error. 
I could rescue within the initializer, however that seems not common.

How could I work around this in more ruby way?

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly opinion and anecdotal, but I prefer to deal with casting my values as far up the chain as possible.  So i would find the invoice before this object and pass it in as an argument, same with the card_detail.

If you do that in this class, it will limit the responsibility to coordinating those two objects, which is way easier to test but also adds another layer that you have to reason about in the future.

So how i would handle, split this into 4 separate things

1. Invoice Finder thing
2. Card Finder thing
3. Pdf Generator that takes invoice and card as arguments
4. Finally, something to orchestrate the 3 actions above

Hope this helps.

Addition: Check out the book confident ruby by avdi grimm.  It's really great for outlining handling this type of scenario.

Comment: Thanks! I agree, and I have the book already, but not yet read that much. I figured out why I did this, because I asynchronously generate and send a receipt, so maybe the credit card is changed right after putting queuing, it might be a problem.